# Unable to cast object of type

Tags: c#, wpf

I get an error trying to send a string from one window to another in my wpf application:

> Unable to cast object of type 'WpfApplication4.LoginWindow' to type 'WpfApplication4.MainWindow'.

In my login window the error is on this line:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).StudentID = UserAuthenticationID;
```

In my main window I have this to test:

```
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Content = StudentID;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

No answer has made sense so far, which will be due to my obscure question, I created a wpf application and I have two windows MainWindow.xaml and LoginWindow.xaml.

I want to pass a string (student id) from the login window to the main window after authentication.

I thought the above method was how to do it, as I read it: `((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).StudentID` says where I am intending the string `UserAuthenticationID` to be sent to?

Then in the `MainWindow.xaml` I get the string `UserAuthenticationID` and set it, I then assign a labels content to this public string?

Comment: Your property looks strange. Why are you calling the same property name in its accessors? Why are you assigning to `value` in the setter instead of the other way around?

Comment: Um... won't that `get` property cause a recursive loop and eventual stack overflow?

Comment: The way I read it was I am trying to "Get" the StudentID from the login window and then set its value?

Comment: I think my second answer ("It looks like...") gives the you the most obvious/standard way to do what you want.

Comment: someone seriously needs to address why its so difficult to send information between windows in wpf.

Comment: Please fix your set property I.e: public string StudentId { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks I have done, and reflected in edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you create your login window from your main window.  If you need to reference your main window from your login window then pass a main window reference to your login window when you construct it.  Eg

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    LoginWindow login = new LoginWindow(this);
    login.ShowDialog();
}

class LoginWindow : Window {
    MainWindow app_window;
    public LoginWindow(MainWindow app_window) {
        Owner = app_window;
        this->app_window = app_window;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Error coming because its trying to convert `Application.Current.MainWindow` to `MainWindow`, which is infact `LoginWindow`.

suggestion when you are coverting one object other made check before it

```
if(Application.Current.MainWindow is MainWindow)
{
 /// than do the code 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Application.Current.MainWindow is of Type LoginWindow. But you want to cast it to MainWindow. Both derive (maybe) from Window. But you can't cast a derived class to another derived class.

//Edit

try

```
((LoginWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

or change your Application.Current.MainWindow to a object of type MainWindow

//Edit 2
I think i understood what your intention was. You could try the following:

In your LoginWindow where you press the Button "Login" handle the Buttonevent (Click), get the ID whereever it comes (TextBox) from, put it in a new instance of MainWindow and set the

```
Application.Current.MainWindow
```

to the new instance of MainWindow. If I'm wrong on how you will do it, you should give more facts.

Other solution is the LoginDialog solution from Ricibob.

Comment: It doesn't exist because you put the StudentID property in your MainWindow class. Does it exist in your LoginWindow class?

Comment: Then how am I suppose to reference the StudentID in the main window?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your trying to feed the UserAuthenticationID from your login dialog back to your main window where you store it as StudentId.
Why not handle that back in the main window Eg:

```
if (login.ShowDialog())
    StudentId = login.UserAuthenticationID;
```

Comment: He didn't say anything about an Dialog. I think his MainWindow is a LoginWindow derived from Window.

Comment: She and yes your correct, in wpfapplication I just right clicked added new wpf window.

Comment: ShowDialog is method of Window.  Dialogs dont exit in WPF - only Windows.  Please dont vote down somethign your not informed about.

Comment: I didn't vote down anything. And I didn't say that your solution is NOT aimed on a Window as dialog. But she has another intention on how to design her application. So if you try to help a obvious newbie to wpf, help in a productive way. Especially this answer is less productive. I'm sorry for typos and wrong grammar, it's not my first language.

Comment: If were talking main windows and login in windows then it seems reasonable to assume a. Main window loaded.  b. Main window shows login window (via ShowDialog?). c. Main window gets back info from login window if it was oked.  Thats just how I understood the question and thats how Ive done login dialogs.

Comment: @Ricibob no the main window doesnt show a dialog, when the application is first started the user is taken to a login window if the authentication is correct proceed to main window. And I did mention in the first line `I get an error trying to send a string from one window to another in my wpf application`

Comment: I would guess that Application.Current.MainWindow could not be a dialog. But the error says, that the Application.Current.MainWindow is a LoginWindow. So if you try to suggest another solution to her, do it in a helpful way or let it be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure the design of your program.  What you want to do isn't terribly hard; you're essentially asking for a good way to communicate between forms.

First off, I suggest not using `Application.Current.MainWindow` unless you're really sure you need to.  You can get apps to work using it, but it's not good design and leads to problems.

We'll start off with the definition of some `OtherWindow` that will be the popup.

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for OtherWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class OtherWindow : Window
    {
        public OtherWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string SomeData
        {
            get
            {
                //you'll probably want to return the value of a textbox or something else 
                //the user fills in.
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From a communication point of view, all that's really important is that it has a property (or properties) with the information that the main form will need to access.  Obviously I've omitted all of the code for actually collecting the data to return and instead hard code a value for this example.

Now for the mainform.  (All I've added is a button and a label.)

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OtherWindow other = new OtherWindow();
            other.Closed += (sender2, e2) =>
                {
                    label1.Content = other.SomeData;
                };

            //either of the methods below, depending on desired behavior.
            other.Show();
            //other.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

While there are quite a lot of ways of making different windows/forms communicate, this is my favorite.  All of the logic for the interaction between the windows is in once place (the button click event).  The main form clearly "owns" `OtherWindow`, and `OtheWindow` doesn't need to know a thing about `MainWindow`, it only need to know how to collect some information.  `MainWindow` will take care of pulling out the information that it needs.

The code for the button click even reads just like what you want it to do: create a new window, when it's closed, set its content to my label, and show the form.  It's all in once place, and in the order that I logically think through it (you can attach the event handler after `Show` if you want).

Oh, and this is exactly the same way that I would do this in a winforms app too, in case anyone cares, barring the fact that some of the class/property names will be different.