# WPF: Can't clear Grid that contains UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, grid

On MainWindow, I try to load UserControl1 and clear the Grid, but Clear doesn't work.

I have a Grid on UserControl1 like:

```
<Grid>
<Button  Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Clear Grid Button</Button>
</Grid>
```

Behind code of UserControl:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
MainWindow main=new MainWindow();
main.ClearGrid();
}
```

And on MainWindow we try to add this userControl to Grid and Clear it.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1s.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
    <Grid Name="main">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Behind code of MainWindow:

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
main.Children.Add(new UserControl1());
}


public void ClearGrid()
{
main.Children.Clear();

}
```

Comment: `new MainWindow()` - you are clearing grid of another (new) window. Try `this.ClearGrid()`.

Comment: `((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ClearGrid();`

Comment: Or just `((Panel)Parent).Children.Remove(this);`

Comment: @Clemens ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow) this works fine, thanks, please add a answer, going to accept :)

Comment: Safer: `(Parent as Panel)?.Children.Remove(this);`

Comment: @Clemens facing with this problem on real project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319735/unable-to-cast-object-of-type